# Can we do SSR only using CRA?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

We are coding in a very complex app in CRA and now our client want to change some page to SSR. We have just one week so can't migrate to Nextjs. Any solution?

Comment: a creepy client, to put it mildly

Comment: At first they think 3 days but some how my PM did his job and we have some more days

Comment: See [`react-com/client#hydrateRoot()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-client.html#hydrateroot) and [`ReactDOMServer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)